# Create and populate a column with value chosen from a specific date per group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with multiple groups (location, animal, color) for instance.

I want to create a new column FY_19 such that for all Year 2020 rows, I can see the corresonding group's full year 2019 value (which is readily available in the 2019_YTD column matching Date = 2019-12-01)

```
Current DF

Location Animal Color Date       2019_YTD
Asia     Dog    Blue  2019-06-01    20
Asia     Dog    Red   2019-06-01    30
Africa    Cat   Blue  2019-06-01    20
Africa    Dog    Red   2019-06-01    30
Asia     Dog    Blue  2019-12-01    30
Asia     Dog    Red   2019-12-01    50
Africa    Cat   Blue  2019-12-01    60
Africa    Dog    Red   2019-12-01    55  
Asia     Dog    Blue  2020-06-01    
Asia     Dog    Red   2020-06-01    
Africa    Cat   Blue  2020-06-01    
Africa    Dog    Red   2020-06-01    
Asia     Dog    Blue  2020-12-01   
Asia     Dog    Red   2020-12-01    
Africa    Cat   Blue  2020-12-01    
Africa    Dog    Red   2020-12-01    



Desired DF
Location Animal Color Date       2019_YTD    FY19
Asia     Dog    Blue  2019-06-01    20
Asia     Dog    Red   2019-06-01    30
Africa    Cat   Blue  2019-06-01    20
Africa    Dog    Red   2019-06-01    30
Asia     Dog    Blue  2019-12-01    30
Asia     Dog    Red   2019-12-01    50
Africa    Cat   Blue  2019-12-01    60
Africa    Dog    Red   2019-12-01    55  
Asia     Dog    Blue  2020-06-01            30
Asia     Dog    Red   2020-06-01            50
Africa    Cat   Blue  2020-06-01            60
Africa    Dog    Red   2020-06-01           55
Asia     Dog    Blue  2020-12-01            30
Asia     Dog    Red   2020-12-01            50
Africa    Cat   Blue  2020-12-01            60
Africa    Dog    Red   2020-12-01           55
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) only filtered rows and then replace values to missing if no `2020` year:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Location': ['Asia', 'Asia', 'Africa', 'Africa', 'Asia', 'Asia', 'Africa', 'Africa', 'Asia', 'Asia', 'Africa', 'Africa', 'Asia', 'Asia', 'Africa', 'Africa'], 'Animal': ['Dog', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Dog', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Dog', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Dog', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Dog'], 'Color': ['Blue', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Red'],
                   'Date': [pd.Timestamp('2019-06-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-06-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-06-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-06-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-12-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-12-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-12-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-12-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-06-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-06-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-06-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-06-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-12-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-12-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-12-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-12-01 00:00:00')],
                   '2019_YTD': [20.0, 30.0, 20.0, 30.0, 30.0, 50.0, 60.0, 55.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

print (df)
   Location Animal Color       Date  2019_YTD
0      Asia    Dog  Blue 2019-06-01      20.0
1      Asia    Dog   Red 2019-06-01      30.0
2    Africa    Cat  Blue 2019-06-01      20.0
3    Africa    Dog   Red 2019-06-01      30.0
4      Asia    Dog  Blue 2019-12-01      30.0
5      Asia    Dog   Red 2019-12-01      50.0
6    Africa    Cat  Blue 2019-12-01      60.0
7    Africa    Dog   Red 2019-12-01      55.0
8      Asia    Dog  Blue 2020-06-01       NaN
9      Asia    Dog   Red 2020-06-01       NaN
10   Africa    Cat  Blue 2020-06-01       NaN
11   Africa    Dog   Red 2020-06-01       NaN
12     Asia    Dog  Blue 2020-12-01       NaN
13     Asia    Dog   Red 2020-12-01       NaN
14   Africa    Cat  Blue 2020-12-01       NaN
15   Africa    Dog   Red 2020-12-01       NaN
```

---

```
cols = ['Location','Animal','Color','2019_YTD']
df1 = df.loc[df['Date'] == '2019-12-01', cols].rename(columns={'2019_YTD':'FY19'})
print (df1)
  Location Animal Color  FY19
4     Asia    Dog  Blue  30.0
5     Asia    Dog   Red  50.0
6   Africa    Cat  Blue  60.0
7   Africa    Dog   Red  55.0

df = df.merge(df1, how='left')
print (df)
   Location Animal Color       Date  2019_YTD  FY19
0      Asia    Dog  Blue 2019-06-01      20.0  30.0
1      Asia    Dog   Red 2019-06-01      30.0  50.0
2    Africa    Cat  Blue 2019-06-01      20.0  60.0
3    Africa    Dog   Red 2019-06-01      30.0  55.0
4      Asia    Dog  Blue 2019-12-01      30.0  30.0
5      Asia    Dog   Red 2019-12-01      50.0  50.0
6    Africa    Cat  Blue 2019-12-01      60.0  60.0
7    Africa    Dog   Red 2019-12-01      55.0  55.0
8      Asia    Dog  Blue 2020-06-01       NaN  30.0
9      Asia    Dog   Red 2020-06-01       NaN  50.0
10   Africa    Cat  Blue 2020-06-01       NaN  60.0
11   Africa    Dog   Red 2020-06-01       NaN  55.0
12     Asia    Dog  Blue 2020-12-01       NaN  30.0
13     Asia    Dog   Red 2020-12-01       NaN  50.0
14   Africa    Cat  Blue 2020-12-01       NaN  60.0
15   Africa    Dog   Red 2020-12-01       NaN  55.0
```

---

```
print (df['Date'].dt.year == 2020)
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8      True
9      True
10     True
11     True
12     True
13     True
14     True
15     True
Name: Date, dtype: bool
```

---

```
df['FY19'] = df['FY19'].where(df['Date'].dt.year == 2020)
print (df)
   Location Animal Color       Date  2019_YTD  FY19
0      Asia    Dog  Blue 2019-06-01      20.0   NaN
1      Asia    Dog   Red 2019-06-01      30.0   NaN
2    Africa    Cat  Blue 2019-06-01      20.0   NaN
3    Africa    Dog   Red 2019-06-01      30.0   NaN
4      Asia    Dog  Blue 2019-12-01      30.0   NaN
5      Asia    Dog   Red 2019-12-01      50.0   NaN
6    Africa    Cat  Blue 2019-12-01      60.0   NaN
7    Africa    Dog   Red 2019-12-01      55.0   NaN
8      Asia    Dog  Blue 2020-06-01       NaN  30.0
9      Asia    Dog   Red 2020-06-01       NaN  50.0
10   Africa    Cat  Blue 2020-06-01       NaN  60.0
11   Africa    Dog   Red 2020-06-01       NaN  55.0
12     Asia    Dog  Blue 2020-12-01       NaN  30.0
13     Asia    Dog   Red 2020-12-01       NaN  50.0
14   Africa    Cat  Blue 2020-12-01       NaN  60.0
15   Africa    Dog   Red 2020-12-01       NaN  55.0
```

Comment: its all Nan in FY19 column for Year 2020 rows

Comment: @asimo - Can you test `print (df1)`?

Comment: @asimo - Solution was a bit changed, you ca check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60485436/revisions)

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, the problem is actually at the df['FY19'] = df['FY19'].where(df['Date'].dt.year == 2020) step.
The df contains nan values as well, and it simply populates everything nan.

Comment: @asimo - Thid line onlt set missing values for rows with no `2020` datetimes, logic is different?

Comment: Yes this line is only for populating or filling rows with 2020 data with the corresponding FY19 value taken from Dec 19..right ? But it does not work as expected

Comment: @asimo - No, this line only set NaNs for rows with no 2020 year in `Date` column.

Comment: It is setting Nan for all rows..(not just 2019)

Comment: i should rather use ffill (sorted on date, and takes into consideration combination keys of location animal color

Comment: @asimo - Answer was edited, if not working data has to be different.

Comment: @asimo - If `df['Date'].dt.year == 2020` return all `False` then it should be reason for all `NaN`s